# Changing letters for uppercased in a given string - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, iteration

i'm trying to write a function which will create a list of a strings based on the same word but with different letters uppercased. Currently I have something like this:

```
word = 'passwordPASSWORD'

def generator():
    list_ = []
    result = itertools.permutations(word, (len(word)//2)))
    for el in result:
        x = ''.join(list(map(lambda x: x.lower(), el)))
        if x == 'password':
            list_.append(''.join(el))
    return list_

generator()
```

as a result I need to have (it will be short as example) list_ = [password, pAssword, PaSSwORd ,passWORD, ......etc.]
I have tried with itertools.permutation but for longer word(like password), script is not able to finish iteration.

Thanks in advance for any support with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's using `product` from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import product

word = 'password'

[''.join(x) for x in product(
    *[[l.upper(), l.lower()] for l in word])]
```

Output:

```
['PASSWORD',
 'PASSWORd',
 'PASSWOrD',
 'PASSWOrd',
 'PASSWoRD',
 'PASSWoRd',
 'PASSWorD',
 'PASSWord',
 'PASSwORD',
 'PASSwORd',
 'PASSwOrD',
 'PASSwOrd',
 'PASSwoRD',
 'PASSwoRd',
 'PASSworD',
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this function:

```py
def all_casings(input_string):
    if not input_string:
        yield ""
    else:
        first = input_string[:1]
        if first.lower() == first.upper():
            for sub_casing in all_casings(input_string[1:]):
                yield first + sub_casing
        else:
            for sub_casing in all_casings(input_string[1:]):
                yield first.lower() + sub_casing
                yield first.upper() + sub_casing
```

And call it like this:

```py
[x for x in all_casings("foo")]
```